# calculate bias hidden layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have developped in python a small code which is using 4 neurons (2 inputs, 3 neurons in hidden layer, and 1 output neuron) the code is really specific cause i wanted to understand every operation carefully.
It works but I still have one problem with bias !

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    layer1, predictions = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weights_13, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_13, bias_output)
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        layer1, predictions = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weights_13, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_13, bias_output)
        print (cost(predictions, targets))
    """
        There are a lot of things to do here !
        to do the back propagation, we will first train the ouput neural
    """
    #Init gradient
    weights_gradient_output = np.zeros(weight_ouput.shape)
    bias_gradient_output = 0

    weights_gradient_11 = np.zeros(weights_11.shape)
    bias_gradient_11 = 0

    weights_gradient_12 = np.zeros(weights_12.shape)
    bias_gradient_12 = 0

    weights_gradient_13 = np.zeros(weights_12.shape)
    bias_gradient_13 = 0
    #Go throught each row
    for neural_input, feature, target, prediction in zip(layer1, features, targets, predictions):

        output_error = prediction - target
        output_delta = output_error * derivative_activation_y(prediction)

        error_neural_hidden_11 = output_delta * weight_ouput[0]
        error_neural_hidden_12 = output_delta * weight_ouput[1]
        error_neural_hidden_13 = output_delta * weight_ouput[2]


        error_neural_11 = error_neural_hidden_11 * derivative_activation_y(neural_input[0])
        error_neural_12 = error_neural_hidden_12 * derivative_activation_y(neural_input[1])
        error_neural_13 = error_neural_hidden_13 * derivative_activation_y(neural_input[2])

        weights_gradient_output += neural_input * output_delta
        #bias_output += output_delta

        weights_gradient_11 += feature * error_neural_11
        #bias_11 += error_neural_11

        weights_gradient_12 += feature * error_neural_12
        #bias_12 += error_neural_12

        weights_gradient_13 += feature * error_neural_13
        #bias_13 += error_neural_13


    #Update the weights and bias
    weight_ouput = weight_ouput - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_output)
    bias_output = bias_output - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_output)
    weights_11 =  weights_11 - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_11)
    bias_11 =  bias_11 - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_11)
    weights_12 =  weights_12 - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_12)
    bias_12 =  bias_12 - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_12)
    weights_13 =  weights_13 - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_13)
    bias_13 =  bias_13 - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_13)
```

This is giving me good results, but as soon as I uncomment lines where I modify the bias of each neurons, it goes super wrong ! It converges to 0.5 (like 0,4999999)

Do you know why ? it looks like the update of the bias gradient is good, isnt it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your gradient accumulation code here,

```
    weights_gradient_output += neural_input * output_delta
    #bias_output += output_delta
```

You are adding your gradients directly to the bias instead of to `bias_gradient_output`. Consequently, your bias updates use a learning rate of 1, which is probably higher than you intended. (Similar problem with `bias_11`, etc).